# Bouncycastle CMSException

Tags: java, bouncycastle

Why bouncycastle Exception is thrown when data format is correct.

```
@SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "deprecation"}) 
     public static boolean verifySign(String base64Data, String base64SignedData)
                 throws Exception {
         /* to add BouncyCastleProvider */
           Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
           /* to add BouncyCastleProvider end */
           boolean verifiedStatus = false; 
           CMSSignedData cmsSignedData = null;
           X509Certificate cert = null;
        //   LOGGER.info("Entering verifySign at {}", System.currentTimeMillis());
           System.out.println("Entering verifySign at {}"+System.currentTimeMillis());  
           try { 
                // LOGGER.debug("base64Data and base64SignedData {} ", base64Data,    base64SignedData);
                 System.out.println("base64Data {}="+base64Data);
                 System.out.println(" base64SignedData{}="+ base64SignedData);   
                 byte[] signedBytes = Base64.decodeBase64(base64SignedData);
     cmsSignedData = new CMSSignedData(  new CMSProcessableByteArray(base64Data.getBytes()),signedBytes);

                 CertStore certStore = cmsSignedData.getCertificatesAndCRLs("Collection", "BC");
                 Collection signers = cmsSignedData.getSignerInfos().getSigners();
                 Iterator signersIterator = signers.iterator();
                 while (signersIterator.hasNext()) {
                       SignerInformation signer = (SignerInformation) signersIterator.next();
                       Collection certCollection = certStore.getCertificates(signer.getSID());
                       Iterator certIt = certCollection.iterator(); 
                       cert = (X509Certificate) certIt.next();
                       System.out.println("public key"+cert.getPublicKey());
                       verifiedStatus = signer.verify(cert.getPublicKey(), "BC");  
                 }
                // LOGGER.debug("Signature verification status {} ", verifiedStatus);
                 System.out.println("Signature verification status {} ::"+ verifiedStatus);
           } catch (CMSException cmse) {
                // LOGGER.error("CMSException in verifySign", cmse);
                 System.out.println("CMSException in verifySign"+cmse);
                 throw cmse; 
           } catch (Exception e) {
                 //LOGGER.error("Exception in verifySign", e);
                 System.out.println("Exception in verifySign"+e);
                 throw e;
           } finally {
               //  LOGGER.info("Exiting verifySign at {}", System.currentTimeMillis());
                 System.out.println("Exiting verifySign at {}"+System.currentTimeMillis());
           }
           return verifiedStatus;
     }
```

A `CMSException` is thrown in `verifySign`:

```
org.bouncycastle.cms.CMSSignerDigestMismatchException:
message-digest attribute value does not match calculated value
Exiting verifySign at {}1495630515140
Exception in thread "main" org.bouncycastle.cms.CMSSignerDigestMismatchException:
message-digest attribute value does not match calculated value
    at org.bouncycastle.cms.SignerInformation.doVerify(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.cms.SignerInformation.verify(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.cms.SignerInformation.verify(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: instead of returning verifiedStatus.

Comment: Post a complete stack trace and more details. Given information is not sufficient.

Comment: @AmitChandan - you can edit the question to add this information (much better to read than in the comments)

Comment: @AmitChandan update the trace in question itself. It would be more understandable.

Comment: I want the method to return only true or false but it throws exception.

Comment: Hey I'm facing the same issue... Have u resolved this problem ??@AmitChandan

Answer (score 6):

I'm using **BouncyCastle 1.56** (so some things might differ if you use another version).

This error happens because BouncyCastle checks the [Message Digest attribute](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5652#section-11.2), which is inside the `SignerInformation` field. If this attribute is different from the content digest, the exception is thrown.

You can check if these fields are different with this code (I'm not checking for **nulls**, which might happen if the attribute is not present):

```
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.DEROctetString;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.cms.Attribute;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.cms.AttributeTable;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.cms.CMSAttributes;


SignerInformation signer = // this one you already have
AttributeTable attributes = signer.getSignedAttributes();
Attribute attribute = attributes.get(CMSAttributes.messageDigest);
DEROctetString digest = (DEROctetString) attribute.getAttrValues().getObjectAt(0);

// if these values are different, the exception is thrown
System.out.println(Hex.toHexString(digest.getOctets()));
System.out.println(Hex.toHexString(signer.getContentDigest()));
```

Comment: Thanks Hugo,I will use this code in my  method to handle this  exception.

Comment: @AmitChandan Good! If this answer was useful, you can also upvote and/or accept it: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I wonder how I could end up in the situation where I get the same exception as the question-asker *but* the two values are actually the same!?